# one-sided inverses for ideals of finite algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-fields

Let $k$ be a finite field and $A$ be a finite $k$-algebra. Assume we are given zero divisor $x$ in $A$ and consider the left ideal $Ax$. In (a), Rónyai assumes that one can find a right identity $r$ of $Ax$. Of course, this would exist if we could solve $a_ie=a_i$ for a basis $\{a_i\}$ of $A$, and if we express $e$ as $e=\sum_j\varepsilon_j a_j$, this amounts to solving the system of $n^2$ linear equations $\sum_j a_i a_j \lambda_j = a_i$.

However, I do not see why this system should have a solution. The "cube" $(a_i a_j)_{ij}$ is certainly singular since $Ax$ contains zero divisors.

(a) Ronyai: [Computing the structure of finite algebras](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0747-7171(08)80017-X), after lemma 5.1.

Comment: "Computing the structure of finite algebras"?  It is a bit silly to allude to a publication without telling us what it is exactly. Granted there seem to be only two in that year, according to google scholar, but still it isn't good to force readers to do this extra work. It would also help if you cited the particular passage you were looking at.

Comment: @rschwieb I am sorry; the reference has been added.

Comment: Good: and knowing that, the answer seems to be straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

The context is a **lot** more specific than you initially mentioned. In the passage you are citing, we are talking about matrix algebras over fields.

It is well-known that every left ideal $L$ of a matrix algebra is generated by an idempotent $e$ (that is, $L=Re$), and that idempotent acts as a right identity of the left ideal, since $(Re)e=Ree=Re$.

That all left ideals are generated by idempotents is an easy consequence of the fact that the matrix ring has identity and that every left ideal is a direct summand.

The statement does not hold for finite algebras in general. For example, take $F_2[x]/(x^3)$ and let $A=(x)/(x^3)$ and the ideal $(x^2)/(x^3)$ has no left or right identity.